# How to run through loop to use non-scaled and scaled data in python for loop

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have the following code running through and fitting a model on the iris data using different modeling techniques. How can I add a second step in this process so I can demonstrate the improvement between using scaled and non-scaled data?

I don't need to run the scale transform outside of the loop, i was just having a lot of issues with transforming the data type from pandas dataframe to np array and back again.

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :2]  # we only take the first two features.
y = iris.target


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.2)


sc = StandardScaler()
X_train_scale = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_scale = sc.transform(X_test)

numFolds = 10
kf = KFold(len(y_train), numFolds, shuffle=True)

# These are "Class objects". For each Class, find the AUC through
# 10 fold cross validation.
Models = [LogisticRegression, svm.SVC]
params = [{},{}]

for param, Model in zip(params, Models):
    total = 0
    for train_indices, test_indices in kf:

        train_X = X_train[train_indices]; train_Y = y_train[train_indices]
        test_X = X_train[test_indices]; test_Y = y_train[test_indices]

        reg = Model(**param)
        reg.fit(train_X, train_Y)
        predictions = reg.predict(test_X)
        total += accuracy_score(test_Y, predictions)
    accuracy = total / numFolds

    print ("CV accuracy score of {0}: {1}".format(Model.__name__, round(accuracy, 6)))
```

So ideally my output would be:

```
CV standard accuracy score of LogisticRegression: 0.683333
CV scaled accuracy score of LogisticRegression: 0.766667
CV standard accuracy score of SVC: 0.766667
CV scaled accuracy score of SVC: 0.783333
```

It seems like this is unclear, I am trying to loop through scaled and unscaled data, similar to how I am looping through the different ML algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to follow up with this. I was able to do this by creating a pipeline and using gridsearchCV

```
pipe = Pipeline([('scale', StandardScaler()), 
                 ('clf', LogisticRegression())])
param_grid = [{
        'scale':[None,StandardScaler()],
        'clf':[SVC(),LogisticRegression()]}]
grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid=param_grid,n_jobs=-1, verbose=1 )
```

In the end this got me the results I wanted and was able to test easily how to work between scaling and not scaling.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from __future__ import division

for param, Model in zip(params, Models):
    total = 0
    for train_indices, test_indices in kf:
        train_X = X_train[train_indices]; train_Y = y_train[train_indices]
        test_X = X_train[test_indices]; test_Y = y_train[test_indices]
        reg = Model(**param)
        reg.fit(train_X, train_Y)
        predictions = reg.predict(test_X)
        total += accuracy_score(test_Y, predictions)
        accuracy = total / numFolds
        print ("CV accuracy score of {0}: {1}".format(Model.__name__, round(accuracy, 6)))

        # added to your code
        if previous_accuracy:
           improvement = 1 - (accuracy / previous_accuracy)
           print "CV accuracy score improved by", improvement
        else:
            previous_accuracy = accuracy
```

Comment: This looks like it is comparing accuracy results to print the best one, the sample output just happened to have that pattern. Rather I am looking to incorporate scaling data in the loop.

Comment: After reading again, I admit that you are correct - let me have a look again, I will see what I can do